# What Facebook libraries are there for Scala?

Tags: facebook, scala

looking for something other than a generic Java library.

Comment: Try to be more specific about `Facebook library`.

Comment: Hmm.   Seems like a legitimate question to me.

Comment: It would be better if zak23 had specified what he intends the library to do. One of the answer, from Lift, is obviously a server-side library. I'd look for a library for Dispatch, which would be a client-side library. But Scala + Facebook is specific enough that one can tell whether an answer is right or wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Lift has a facebook module:  https://github.com/lift/modules/tree/master/facebook

Comment: But Lift facebook module is based on Rest API and not on latest Graph APIs

Answer (score 0):

I am activly developing one - https://github.com/vooolll/facebook4s